# Can I use EP 80W/90 oil instead of EP90 oil?

Tags: oil, gears, gear-oil

I have a Belle MiniMix 150 110V Electric Cement Mixer  the documentation says to use a EP90 oil in the gear box, but these days it seems that most outlets only sells EP80/90 oil.

What is the difference and does it matter?

(I am asking on a mechanics.stackexchange as I need advice for people that understand gear boxes and oils.)

Comment: asked and answered answered on [diy.sx](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/38745/can-i-use-ep-80w-90-oil-instead-of-ep90-oil-in-a-belle-minimix-150-gearbox)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

80W90 is a multiviscosity version of the single-viscosity 90 gear oil; it's the same concept as 10W30 motor oil being the multiviscosity version of single-viscosity 30-weight motor oil. The "W" is a "winter" rating, meaning that the oil in question is designed to be usable in winter months in cold climates.

80W90 oil is perfectly satisfactory for your purposes in a cement mixer - it can be either GL4 (with very little molybdenum disulfide) or GL5 (with lots of moly-d)... for a cement mixer I'd recommend using the GL5 because you have no brass synchro components for the moly-d to attack. GL4 is for older manual transmissions that can't tolerate moly-d because they contain brass. For gearboxes that can use it, moly-d adds extra protection against wear, especially in cases where regular maintenance is unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

much like motor vehicles (depending on age) some makers recommend mineral based oils
some synthetic.They do this for a reason as viscosity/additives vary.Use what they specify.Lubricant makers have websites,some of whom allow you to pose questions regarding
lubricants and applications